# React Native app doesn't load @1x, @2x or @3x image to the right screen density

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, responsive-design

I am developing a iOS/Android app using React Native. According to the documentation at this link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images
React native places the correct image size according to your device screen density.

When developing I do as the tutorial on the link above but react native bundles de img.png always and doesn't place the @2x or @3x image which are bigger.

I don't know if this is only done when the bundle is created for launching the app or so! Please help, I am struggling

Also, which is the better flux, process or way to design one screen size in psd and get all assets for multiple screen sizes from it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For example, I exported a shape made in adobe XD in iphone 6s plus, then exported in 1x, 2x and 3x designed at 3x. Then put those images in react native and didn't work. Did I exported them wrong from react native?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as react-native doc image should be named accordingly [image]

in development mode images will be bundled to app but you can link images in native project folder as `drawable`   in android 
so if you use different builds for your app you will use that density images

#### ps : a dirty workaround inorder to test your app in dev mode is, providing other image for @2x or @3x image sizes

Comment: Yes I link the images in Xcode for iOS and then will do it for Android. 

I have that same file structure and it doesn't load the image I want to view in the screen

Comment: does it load images without @2x

Comment: I did what you told me to use another image for @2x and it works but the images doesn't look the same in different sizes, I used a shape with different color for @x for testing

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - my `@2x` and `@3x` images weren't being loaded when I compiled and ran my app on phones with those screen densities, after I added them to the project.

But when I stopped and closed the bundler (terminal) and restarted it (new terminal window), it packaged and displayed the correct density images on the correct devices' screens.